# Determine Orthogonal and non orthogonal using Coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Can we identify using coordinates that if Polygon is orthogonal or non orthogonal.

> data = [(100, 100), (100, 200), (300, 200), (600, 400), (1150, 400),
>   (1150,300), (600,300), (300,100)](These data point create following
>   NON orthogonal Polygon)
>
> data = [(550 , 221), (800 , 221), (800 , 269), (1090 , 269), (1090 , 173), 
>   (1520 , 173), (1520 , 269), (1810 , 269), (1810 , 173), (2420
>   , 173), (2420 , 221), (2708 , 221), (2708 , 317), (550 , 317) ]
>
> These data point create orthogonal Polygon

Comment: No I am receiving coordinates as Input. So The order of ordinates is not fixed

Comment: So, you're asking the question: "Given a collection of points in the plane, is it possible to construct a orthogonal polygonal whose vertices are these points?"

Comment: What do you mean by orthogonal polygon. In $\mathbb R^2$ this would be a rectangle, right? If not, how would you define an orthogonal polygon?

Comment: @Gary I think that the OP means a [rectilinear polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_polygon).  Although it is not clear if the OP would like an axis-aligned polygon.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Orthogonal polygon : it's have 90 degress with edges. rectilinear polygon

Comment: Are you assuming that the sides of the polygon are axis-aligned?

Comment: Yes but as we are begining phase of development so I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sides of the polygon are axis aligned:

If you include the extra condition that the vertices are in general position (no three have the same $x$ coordinate and no three have the same $y$ coordinate), then given a set of points, there is a *unique* rectilinear polygon that can be constructed from them.

In that case, you can order the points easily and take the dot product between vectors of successive pairs of points to determine if the polygon has only right angles (the dot products should all be zero).

If you do not include the general position assumption, the polygon is not unique.  If you do not assume that the polygon is axis-aligned, you could start by considering the directions from one point to all other points, and see if any of them give data sets in general position.

Comment: One question.  I was looking into dot product. How will I achieve using coordinates. I mean, do I need to separated x and y co-ordinate and make vector

Comment: @user765443 To compute the vectors and their dot product, take successive, coordinate-wise differences between the points and use those coordinates to take the dot product.

Comment: For example, in your second example, the first three points are $(550 , 221), (800 , 221), (800 , 269)$.  The vector from the first point to the second point is $\langle 800-550,221-221\rangle=\langle 250,0\rangle$.  The vector from the second to the third point is $\langle 800-800,269-221\rangle=\langle 0,48\rangle$.  The dot product of these two vectors, $\langle 250,0\rangle\cdot\langle0,48\rangle=250\cdot 0+0\cdot 48=0$.